# Angular library versioning: should I trust the docs or the CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library

I get mixed signals about whether to expect a library I create to be consumable by an app running a *future* version of Angular.

On one hand, [this page](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#publishing-libraries) in their docs says yes:

> There are two distribution formats to use when publishing a library: Partial-Ivy (recommended) Contains portable code that can be consumed by Ivy applications built with any version of Angular **from v12 onwards**.
>
> ...
>
> The Angular version used to build an application should always be the same **or greater** than the Angular versions used to build any of its dependent libraries.

But on the other hand when I use the Angular CLI to generate a new library, it scaffolds a new `package.json` that requires **the same major version**:

```json
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

If the docs are fully trustworthy, I would expect `package.json` to specify `>=14.0.0`. I hesitate to believe in "forward compatibility", so I am more comfortable with the way they scaffold things. But on the other hand, the docs seem to clearly (and boldly) state that forward compatibility can be relied on.

Does anybody have insight into why the docs say one thing, but the CLI doesn't seem to "trust" it?

Answer (score 0):

The CLI doesn't "trust" future major versions of Angular because there may be **breaking changes** that will prevent your library from working.

It's true that your library can be *published* using any version of Angular 12 or greater via Partial-Ivy, but that doesn't mean that the published library conforms to code requirements in future versions of Angular.

If your library declares `^14.0.0` and a future application using your library wants to upgrade to `15.0.0`, it always has the option of using `--force` to upgrade Angular until your library publishes a version that will definitely work with Angular 15 (by changing the declaration to `^15.0.0`, for example). If the update is forced, and your library can't handle any breaking changes introduced in 15, then the build of the app will fail (or could even fail at runtime in some cases, I assume).

In my opinion, the need to be careful across major Angular versions was the most obvious when upgrading between Angular 5 and 6 because there were huge, code-breaking changes not just with Angular but with RxJS as well. Many users had to wait for their dependencies to update their code to use Angular 6 features before they themselves could update to Angular 6. More recently, there haven't been nearly as many code-breaking changes across major Angular updates.

Summarily:

1. Major version numbers mean breaking changes are possible. So don't assume your library can support major version numbers that don't exist yet.
2. Your app will always be able to be published via Partial-Ivy for any version of Angular 12+ (but that doesn't mean it will compile/build/work).

Comment: I totally understand your logic, but I'm still struggling to reconcile that with the docs I quoted. It does not just say that things can be **published** in partial ivy starting in 12. It says things published in partial ivy can be "**consumed** by Ivy applications built with any version of Angular from v12 onwards", and that an app can have a version "the same **or greater** than the Angular versions used to build any of its dependent libraries." Note that this appeared in their docs starting in v12 - they did not make such claims back in versions 5 or 6.

Comment: It refers to how the library is consumed/understood. With full-Ivy, there is internal code to help the project resolve the published library structure. However, this functional code may differ across major Angular versions, so there is no guarantee of compatibility across versions. With Partial-Ivy, the library is published in a format that does not contain any functionality reliant on internal, non-API Angular code, so there is a guarantee that future versions will support it. But none of that means that the library Angular/TS code will _build_, only that its structure will be understood.

Comment: That seems strange to include in documentation. If I understand you correctly, I could add to their docs something like "The Angular version used to build an application should always be the same or greater than the Angular versions used to build any of its dependent libraries. **But also it might not work if it's greater.**" In that case - why say "or greater" at all?

Comment: It also might work if it's a lower version, but they say you shouldn't rely on that. Then why say it can be greater, if that also only _might_ work?

Comment: Lower versions of Angular do not have the native support for libraries built with Partial-Ivy. Angular 12+ versions do. That's all it's saying. Angular 12+ applications will always understand the published structure of a library built with Partial-Ivy. That says nothing about how functional your library is when it's run with a different version of Angular.

Comment: Or in simpler terms, older Angular projects won't even know what your library _is_, nevermind be able to use it in an application.